# Cannot enable credSSP via PowerShell remote session

Tags: powershell, remoting, credssp

I need to enable credSSP authentication remotely via PowerShell remoting. When running:

```
enable-wsmancredssp -role client -delegatecomputer fqdn -force`
```

I got this error:

```
Access is denied. 
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Enable-WSManCredSSP],  nvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.EnableWSManCredSSPCommand
+ PSComputerName        : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Same error occurs even when executing "get-wsmancredssp"

When I connect to the server via rdp and run the command it runs fine. Is there some policy which prevents enabling this remotely?

Comment: Did you attempt to run this command in a Powershell console that was running with administrative privileges?

Comment: It works when running locally in console with administrator privileges. During remote session I have administrator privileges as well.